# When writing a maven plugin how to specify the allowed maven version

Tags: maven, version, versions-maven-plugin

```
mvn versions:display-plugin-updates
```

displays a line

```
Plugins require minimum Maven version of: 3.9.1
```

I write a plugin and I want to provide also version of maven it works with
so that it shows up in versions plugin.
How can I do this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use `prerequisites` in your plugin project.

It is also good practice to use the same version of Maven Plugin Api and other Maven core artifacts.

So project can look like:

```xml
<project>

...

  <packaging>maven-plugin</packaging>

...

  <prerequisites>
    <maven>${mavenVersion}</maven>
  </prerequisites>

  <properties>
    <mavenVersion>minimum-supported-version</mavenVersion>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
      <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-core</artifactId>
      <version>${mavenVersion}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>

...

</project>
```